# How can I check more than one condition on a logged in user? For instance, user is the author of the article or belongs to a certain role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership

I have a portion of a page that I'll like to display only if the user logged in satisfies any one of the 3 following conditions:

1. He's the author
2. He belongs to the '**Editors**' role.
3. He belongs to the '**Admin**' role.

The object model contains a property called AddedBy (**Model.AddedBy**)

How can I check all the 3 conditions on a ASP.NET MVC page.

So far I've tried the below code

```
<%if((Page.User.Identity.Name == Model.AddedBy) || 
   (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")) || 
   (Page.User.IsInRole("Editors"))){%>

   //Display this portion of page... 

<%}%>
```

But my code doesn't seem to notice the difference and keeps displaying the portion of html enclosed inside the above code.

I must be wrong somewhere.

**EDIT**

The html portion enclosed in the code contains buttons such as **Delete Article, Edit Article, Add Article, Allow Comments**, ... So only the author of the article is supposed to see those buttons or check boxes. Except for the users in Editors role or Admin role can also manipulate articles they don't own.

That way, a user accessing the page can see that portion if he is (i) **the author** OR (ii) belongs to the **Editors role**  OR (iii) to the **Admin role**.

Thanks for helping

Comment: I edited your question to reflect more clearly what your conditions are.  Your code looks right to me so the next step is to debug it.  Is it that you are doing something like setting your Model.AddedBy to the current user ion the controller, so this is always true?  I would put a breakpoint and see what the values are and see if they are what you expect.  when you find the one that is not what you expect you will find your problem.

Comment: I found out (by debugging) that AddedBy was always an empty string. After I've fixed that, everything works fine. In fact, I first thought I didn't write correctly the conditions. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  After clarification of the question by the OP it seems that OR was the condition that should be being used, and that the problem was solved by good old traditional debugging! Hurrah!  What is below is left so the comments make sense, but it now does not answer the modified question.  Might still be useful to someone sometime though...

Is it because you are going to the if condition if **ANY** of those conditions are satisfied (you are using **||** which is **OR**) and not **ALL** of those conditions (you want to use **&&** which is **AND**), which is what your question implies you want?

I think this should give you what you want:

```
<%if((Page.User.Identity.Name == Model.AddedBy) && 
   (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")) && 
   (Page.User.IsInRole("Editors"))){%>

   //Display this portion of page... 

<%}%>
```

using a single & would work as well I think, but using the double && will be slightly more efficient as it will not try to evaluate any subsequent conditions if one is found to be false (and so it would make sense to put the condition which is most often false as the first check in the if statement)

This documentation should be useful: [&& Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [|| Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry if my post is understood that way. In fact, I want to check if at least one of the condition is satisfied. see edit

Comment: What edit?  Why can you not just put a breakpoint in the if statement then and see which is the conditions is `true` when you are not expecting it to be?

Comment: +1 for suggesting analytical and debug skill. Use F9 to put a breakpoint on if condition. applciation will go into debug mode on that line and once you move mouse over the fileds u will see values

Comment: @Swappneel: that's what I've done (I've pressed F9). So, in light of the code I put on the post, what values am I supposed to check for? In fact, when I over fields I see several options.

Comment: @Swappneel: Thanks I just found out what didn't go well by debugging. I don't know how to give you credit as you didn't give an answer but rather a comment.

Comment: What was the issue?  I didn't realise that you would need the basics of debugging pointing out, I had assumed that someone who has asked nearly 150 questions and answered 13 would know how to set a breakpoint and how to interrogate the values of variables at run time.  And @swapneel was just reinforcing *my* suggestion to debug the problem.  I had assumed that this would be the first thing you would have done when it didn't go as expected, not ask for the answer on the internet...

Comment: @Richard77 credit goes to @Sam Holder's answer. I have just reinforced sam's solution for sugegsting to use analytical and debug skill, which matter most than mear coding skills

Comment: Well, @Sam Holder. You are right, I should have checked first only if I was confident with my code. I asked a question on the Internet because I thought I was wrong with the syntax as I was sure that my code should have worked. Never occurred to you that something goes wrong because you use the wrong syntax (even if there's no compile time error)? That's was my case. I though might be I didn't use the right syntax. But, when I was suggested to debug, then I got, it my code was right and it was. So, sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @swapneel: The first time I asked a question on stackoverflow, someone pointed me out that it fairness to always give credit to people who answer questions. As you can see, there's a checkbox to mark someone's post as answer (that's turn it green). In this case, you guys have put comments instead of answers, so there's no way (at least in my knowledge) to check one of your post as the right answer. That's why, to be grateful, I thanked you and said I cannot give you credit. It could have Sam Holder and still not make any difference because I cannot give him credit either. Sorry again.

Comment: @Richard77, its no bother. if it was I would not have answered.  I think the lesson to be learned here is to take things slowly when things don't work as we expect.  go through the code to ensure it seems correct, then debug it to ensure that our expectations are validated before giving up and asking for help.  you could always have tested the syntax with something more simple and verified that the condition worked as expected.  Sorry if my comments came across as a little off hand earlier.  Re-reading them now it seems that they might have.

Comment: You're right. It's important to work hard a problem before giving up. That's also allow several aspects of the problem. Thanks a lot.